# Prepare installer

Tags: c#, installation

I've written small console project which use third party dlls (example: HtmlAgilityPack or Newtonsoft.Json). How can I prepare installer to this project?

I wondering how to do this because the dlls aren't available on the clients computer and the executable doesn't work on it's own.

Comment: While this seems to be a very broad question to me, the best option I found so far was and is [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). You may also need a bootstrapper like [dotNetInstaller](http://dblock.github.com/dotnetinstaller/) if you want to install e.g. the .NET Framework itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For packaging your application (and its dependancies) into an installer, you have multiple solutions :

- [Windows installer setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc185688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) : integrated with VisualStudio (but not in the express one). Simple and easy to use. It can automatically detect, package and deploy the dlls your project depends on.
- [WindowsInstallerXml](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) : Provide much more functions but might be 'overkill' for small projects.
- [InstallShield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx)
- InnoSetup

Comment: I look for install shield - this will works without buy an full version ?

Comment: A free limited edition of install shield exists : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deployment_technologies/archive/2010/04/20/installshield-limited-edition-is-available-for-download-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx